# NoSuchMethodError when calling a method from different class

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to call a method in a different class so I have initiated the class I am trying to access in the class I am calling it from, here is the code:

```
Car c = new Car();
Van Vans = new Van();
SportsCar s = new SportsCar();
MiniVan m  = new MiniVan();

while (SelectMotor < 1 || SelectMotor  > 4) {
    System.out.println("\t\t Choose the vechile you wish to add:");

    System.out.println("1.Car");
    System.out.println("2.Van");
    System.out.println("1.SportsCar");
    System.out.println("4.MiniVan");

    SelectMotor = in.nextInt(); 

    if (SelectMotor == 1) {
        c.AddCar();
    }
```

Whenever I run it I get this error:

[image: NoMethodError]

Here is the code where the method I am calling is contained:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

class Car extends Vehicle {
    Vehicle v = new Vehicle();
    WriteFile WriteCarDetails = new WriteFile(CarDetails, true);
    Scanner SaveCarDetails = new Scanner(System.SaveCarDetails);
    String WriteMe;

    void AddCar() {
        System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\tAdding a Car");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Make: ");
        v.SetMake = SaveCarDetails.next;
        System.out.print("\nEnter Model: ");
        v.SetModel = SaveCarDetails.next;
        System.out.print("\nEnter Litre: ");
        v.SetLitre = SaveCarDetails.nextDouble;
        System.out.println("\nEnter Top Speed: ");
        v.SetTopSpeed = SaveCarDetails.nextInt;
        System.out.println("\nEnter Gears: ");
        v.SetGears = SaveCarDetails.nextInt;
        System.out.println("\nEnter Doors: ");
        v.SetDoors = SaveCarDetails.nextInt;
    }
}
```

I'm new to Java, but have some experience in C#, I can't see why I'm getting the error showing in the picture above, as far as I can see the class I am trying to access is initiated, the name of the method matches. Am I getting the error because I am trying to access a subclass without accessing the superclass first? That's the only weird way I could think its going wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you sure that you correctly compiled `Car.java`?

Comment: Try setting the AddCar() method to `public`.

Comment: I'm assuming the whole program compiled correctly as I access two other classes and navigate through them before trying to access this method.

Comment: `AddCar()` has package access, if `Car` and your other class is not in the same, then you wont have access to this method.

Comment: @COYG Your Java inside the `AddCar()` method isnt valid and shouldnt be compiling. `SaveCarDetails.nextInt` should be `SaveCarDetails.nextInt()`, there is no `nextInt` variable on the `Scanner` class, only the method `nextInt()`.

Comment: @Emd4600 I think that worked,I re-compiled and ran into a number of minor errors in the Car Class (where the method is contained), Will fix the errors and see if that was the problem!

Comment: @ug_ See above comment!

Comment: BTW, you probably don't need `Vehicle v = new Vehicle();` in the `Car` class, as `Car` extends `Vehicle` and so it can access all its methods. Also, I recommend you to follow the [Java Naming Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), so variable and method names should start lowercase.

Comment: @COYG yes you said you *assume* its compiling correctly, however its highly unlikely its compiling due to fatal compile time errors which I pointed out. You might go back and make sure everything is compiling and no errors are getting sucked up somewhere.

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the recommendation, will do.

Comment: Also, you might want to use a IDE like Eclipse, which will detect those kind of errors.

Comment: @COYG If I were a betting man I would put money on the `Car.class` is an old compiled version of your `Car` class and you havent re compiled it since you added that method. Try recompiling all your java files and see if it runs.

Comment: I spoke too soon, still getting the same error. I commented out all of the code in the add car method except for `System.out.println("\n\n\t\t\tAdding a Car");` so it would just return a string, but the error still remains and the string isn't printed, so the method must not be accessed. Using the console @Emd4600 because a couple of people recommend starting with it first then moving onto the IDE.

Comment: Try setting the class `Car` to static. That probably won't fixing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @ug_ Am I suppose to compile all of the classes individually? At the minute I am just compiling the class file where the main method is contained.

Comment: And it worked after compiling the car class. How come you have to do that? Nearly sure that isn't the case in C#, maybe because I was using the IDE and creating console programs through that instead of directly using the command prompt like I am now. What if I were to have 30 classes, would be a pain compiling them individually!

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested in the comments, you may be seeing this issue because the visibility of the `AddCar` method (consider renaming this to `addCar` as doing so will be more in-line with java's naming conventions). Changing this to `public` may help, but if it doesn't ...

Another possibility could be that you may have an older version of the `Car` class on the classpath that doesn't have the `AddCar` method. Since you were able to compile things just fine, it sounds to me like you have the wrong version of the `Car` class on the classpath in your deployment environment.  Try recompiling everything and then make sure that the latest versions of all of your classes are on the classpath in your deployment area.

Comment: The car class wasn't compiled at all, that was the problem, here's the comment I posted above:
And it worked after compiling the car class. How come you have to do that? Nearly sure that isn't the case in C#, maybe because I was using the IDE and creating console programs through that instead of directly using the command prompt like I am now. What if I were to have 30 classes, would be a pain compiling them individually!

Comment: @COYG Maybe consider using Maven or another build system (I personally prefer sbt.) Then an IDE such as IntelliJ or Eclipse. Will make your life easier when working with cumbersome languages such as Java.

Comment: @COYG Yes each individual java file must be compiled individually. This is why IDEs can be so helpful. If you dont want to jump into the IDE world right away I suggest making a simple build script. This could be as simple as a `bat/sh` file or a build tool like ant, maven, ivy ect...

Comment: @COYG Your IDE should be able to compile the entire project automatically. If you're using Eclipse, this should be the case by default, but Eclipse projects have their own classpath issues ... :)

If you really wanna get deep into version control, I suggest learning and using Maven (https://maven.apache.org) - probably way overkill for small projects, but I've been using it for years and don't plan to stop any time soon :)

Comment: @2rs2ts we're thinking the same thing, you just type faster than I do ;)

Comment: I started that Java Head first book and it recommended creating all of the programs in the command prompt so you get an understanding of how the compiling works and what not(the examples were alot smaller than the program am creating), I ended up just creating programs in Java that I've done in C# because a lot of the stuff the book included was very similar to C#. That's really why I'm still using the console. Going to finish a project in this then to get a bit of the understanding they were recommending and then do some projects in an IDE.

Comment: I created a batch file for the compiling @ug_ A lot handier!